# Invalid <url-pattern> null in servlet mapping in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I know that I followed the specification for servlet-mapping and I also created the servlet using Netbeans 7.0.

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Selection</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.package.sample.Selection</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Selection</servlet-name>
  <url-patern>/Selection</url-patern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On catalina log Files

> SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory client
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid  null in servlet mapping
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3130)
>       at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1301)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1350)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1055)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:978)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp.run(WrapperStartStopApp.java:264)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: my school taught me the spelling of `pattern` having a double `t`. `<url-pattern>/Selection</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 1):

The spelling of `pattern` is wrong in the xml file.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Selection</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.package.sample.Selection</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Selection</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Selection</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This is the answer. But If I use that format, whatever class I put in place of "com.package.sample.Selection" gets me the error: "____ is not assignable to javax.servlet.Servlet"